# Excel VB Userform to Complete Missing Data Methodically

Tags: excel, vba, userform

I have a dataset laid out like so:

```
  x  |  y  |  z
row1   abc   xyz
row2   abc   xyz
row3   abc   xyz
```

I need a way for those using the form to methodically fill out the z column whilst reading info contained in the x and y columns.

To this end, I need to add a button that opens a userform. This userform will be similar to a traditional visual basic 'Edit' button in that it pre-loads an existing row of data but will automatically jump to the first row where the z column is empty.

Example: If the data looks like so:

```
 x   |  y  |  z
row1   abc   xyz     123
row2   abc   xyz
row3   abc   xyz

[Edit Records]
```

Then a click of the button will open the userform at row2, as the z column in row1 is complete. They may then complete the z column for row2, save these changes to the master set and click a 'next' button that will move to row3.

Is this feasible in Excel Visual Basic editor and if so, how could this be structured?  Every guide I can find currently can only explain how to jump to the next completely empty row, not based on a particular columns value.

I attempted to create this with a dropdown select row option but the end user has requested a level of automation in finding missing values.

Comment: It is completely feasible. To find a row's first empty cell based on a column you can use: `myRow = .Cells(Rows.Count, "Z").End(xlUp).Row` with "Z" being the column I want to check for the first empty row.

Comment: Thank you. This code is close to what is required but is returning the first completely empty row, rather than the first where only a single column of an otherwise complete dataset is missing.

Comment: Oh so you need to cycle through each column and find the minimum value for `myRow`

Answer (score 0):

To find the first row with any empty cell you can use this type of thing:

```
Sub lastRow()
With Worksheets("Sheet1")
    Dim lRow As Long: lRow = .Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    Dim c As Long
    For c = 2 To 10
        If .Cells(Rows.Count, c).End(xlUp).Row < lRow Then lRow = .Cells(Rows.Count, c).End(xlUp).Row
    Next
End With
MsgBox c
End Sub
```

This routine cycles through columns 1 to 10 (A to L) and produces the first row with an empty cell in those ten columns.